# PHP Session Cookie Not Being Cleared On Browser Close

Tags: php

The following occurs on Chrome, but works perfectly on IE.

a.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['name1'] = 'value1';
```

b.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['name1'];
```

After running `a.php`, I closed the browser and opened a new Chrome window to run `b.php`.
I was surprised it displayed `value1`.

The problem is why the session is still alive when I close the browser?
How to fix it? I want the session being killed when the browser closed.

Comment: are you closing all instances (windows) of chrome?

Comment: How is your cookie set? Can you paste it in your question? Sounds like a cookie lifetime issue without seeing any more.

Comment: You should check the cookies settings of Chrome: chrome://chrome/settings/content

Comment: @AlexandruMihai Yes, not only tabs but all windows

Answer (score 1):

Since it works in IE I would guess the problem in Chrome is because of this feature/design choice:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128513

Especially comment#2 is relevant. Do you have "Continue where I left off" activated in Chrome settings?